# Display rows where a column is False in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with one column(dtype=bool) contains `True`/`False` values, I want to filter the records if bool column == False

Below script gives error, please help.

```
if mFile['CCK'].str.contains(['False']):
    print(mFile.loc[mFile['CCK'] == False])
```

Error in

```
if mFile['CCK'].str.contains(['False']
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need to convert the value to a string (`str.contains`) because it's already a boolean. In fact, since it's a boolean, if you want to keep only the true values, all you need is:

```
mFile[mFile["CCK"]]
```

Assuming mFile is a dataframe and CCK only contains True and False values

Edit: If you want false values use:

```
mFile[~mFile["CCK"]]
```

Answer (score 15):

To display only if a record is `False`, you'll need to invert your condition:

```
mFile[~mFile['CCK']])
```

MVCE:

Original:

```
In [1273]: df
Out[1273]: 
       A    B
0  False    8
1   True   98
2   True   97
3  False  106
4  False   50
5  False   80
6  False   80
7   True   72
8  False  117
9  False   29
```

Using `boolean indexing`:

```
In [1271]: df[~df.A].B
Out[1271]: 
0      8
3    106
4     50
5     80
6     80
8    117
9     29
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

You could also use `pd.Series.mask`:

```
In [1272]: df.B.mask(df.A).dropna()
Out[1272]: 
0      8.0
3    106.0
4     50.0
5     80.0
6     80.0
8    117.0
9     29.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

---

If your data has string entries, you'd need `pd.Series.str.contains`:

```
In [1278]: df[df.A.astype(str).str.contains('False')]
Out[1278]: 
       A    B
0  False    8
3  False  106
4  False   50
5  False   80
6  False   80
8  False  117
9  False   29
```

For your case, it'd be

```
mFile[mFile['CCK'].astype(str).str.contains('False') ]
```

To check if `False-y` values exist, just get the mask and call `pd.Series.any()`:

```
mFile['CCK'].astype(str).str.contains('False').any()
```

Comment: display working fine, but how to apply if mFile['CCK'].contains(['False']) then only display as some data frame as true only

Comment: @faithon Edited my answer.

Comment: @faithon Can you please stick to one person instead of jockeying between answers? Also, more queries go into separate questions. If this worked fine, then you should mark an answer accepted.

Comment: question isn't really clear... i think he just wants to check if at least one `False in mFile['CCK']`...

Comment: @faithon You might consider other methods as I've outlined in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

how about:

```
if False in mFile['CCK']:
    print(mFile[~mFile['CCK']])
```

you can use `~` as above or `mFile['CCK'] == False`, which might be a bit more readable to others...

Comment: thanks.. your code will work, but /i want to display only if it contains false.

Comment: ah, so you want to check up front if any record is false?

Comment: i want to filter  if mFile['CCK'].contains(['False']), display code working fine, error in if condition, how to fix it?